# read row and columns of text file in php

Tags: php

I have a text file the contents of which are as follows:

```
120MB 130MB 140MB 140MB
10% 20% 30% 40%
```

I have a php code which reads the file and prints the column.

```
<?php
$lines = file('test_ssh.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $line);
    echo $parts[2] ;
}
?>
```

by this code I can read columns from the first row as and when required(i.e, if I need to popultae 1st column from 1st row in html table, I can do so by $parts[0])

but I am not able to read second line column by column(i.e. if I just need to read 1st column from 2nd row), I am not able to do it, I just get blank value.

Do I need some 2-D array to read lines and column separately or there is another easier way ? Please help with your expertise.

Comment: Maybe if you show us the result you would like to produce we would understand better what you are asking

Comment: Thanks Riggs, edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you would only want to print one item from the first line and all the occurances from the second. But if this was really what you were asking how to do here is one way.

```
<?php
$lines = file('test_ssh.txt');
foreach ($lines as $lineNo => $line) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $line);
    if ( $lineNo < 1 ) {
        echo $parts[2] . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        foreach( $parts as $col ) {  
            echo $col . ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Result

```
140MB
10% 20% 30% 40%
```

After your comment below

Is this what you wanted

```
$lines = file('test_ssh.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if ( $line == PHP_EOL ) { continue; } // avoid blank lines causing issues
    $columns = explode(' ', $line);
    echo '<tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach( $columns as $col ) {  
        echo '<td>' . trim($col) . '</td>';
    }
    echo PHP_EOL . '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

RESULT

```
<tr>
<td>120MB</td><td>130MB</td><td>140MB</td><td>140MB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10%</td><td>20%</td><td>30%</td><td>40%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

> ignore the `PHP_EOL` in the table output, they are there just to make the output look human readable.

Having reread the updated question, maybe this is what you want

```
function getColfromBothLines($col, $lines)
{
    $lin1 = explode(' ', $lines[0]);
    $lin2 = explode(' ', $lines[1]);
    return $lin1[$col] . ' - ' . $lin2[$col];
}

$lines = file('test_ssh.txt');


echo getColfromBothLines(0, $lines).PHP_EOL;
echo getColfromBothLines(1, $lines).PHP_EOL;
echo getColfromBothLines(2, $lines).PHP_EOL;
```

RESULT

```
120MB - 10%
130MB - 20%
140MB - 30%
```

Comment: My bad Riggs for the confusion, what I mean is that I want to read any particular column from any row, not all the columns of second row and the 3rd one from first one. What I am trying to do is <td>column_value</td>. In my case I was able to popultae all columns one by one as and when required, but for second, all I got was blank while I tried reading any column be it 1st, 2nd or 3rd.

Comment: I had another bash at it. Is that more like you intended?

Comment: Am i any closer now

Comment: Thanks a lot Riggs for the prompt efforts, may be my english is confusing and my question statement is not that clear. I am trying again to explain, request you to bear with me  pls, I just want to display 20% from my text file on browser and nothing else. How do I do it ? If you can help me with that, I will figure oyut rest of the things on my own :)

Comment: Well you could simply change the function to `return $lin2[$col];`

Comment: Thanks Riggs for the help.

Comment: Yeah Riggs you are right, but the issue is that "$lin2[$col];" will return column 1 from line2, ilike wise I can have  $lin3 = explode(' ', $lines[2]);, and then return "return $lin3[$col];", it will again return coulmn 1 of line3. It does not give values of other columns on the same line, i.e. what about column2 from line2(precisely 20% form the sample text file) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this! First foreach for lines and second for explodes.

```
        <?php
        $lines = file('test_ssh.txt');
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            $parts = explode(' ', $line);
            foreach ($parts as $part) {
             echo $part;    
            }
        }
```

Do not close php tag :)

Comment: Thanks sochas, the output from your answer is : 14205MB201MB101MB102MB103MB104MB105MB 106MB107MB

Comment: I'm sorry, I hadn't understood you well :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('file.txt'));
```

Comment: doesn't this do exactly what `file()` does